# ggplot2 - How can I change facet label text using another dataframe as lookup table

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I use ggplot 2.2.0 and R version 3.3.2 w64

According to http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/ I can specify a function to provide the facet labels.
I plot patient data of a study:

[image: image of plotted patient data]

I have a dataframe with the Ids and the data, and I have a second dataframe containing some general information (age and gender)

```
patmeta <- data.frame(
 "pat_id"=c(66, 103, 219, 64, 62, 111, 232),
 "gender"=c("f","f","f", "m","f", "f", "f"), 
 "age"=c(56, 32, 73, 58,37,33,52))
```

I defined a global labeller function and a special one for my pat_id (pat_id_fac is the same as pat_id but as a factor, pat_id is numeric)

```
PatIdLabeller <- function(id) {
    res <- sprintf("Pat %s (%i y, %s)", id,
              subset(patmeta, pat_id == id)$age,
              subset(patmeta, pat_id == id)$gender)
    return(res)
}

globalLabeller <- labeller(
    pat_id_fac = PatIdLabeller,
    pat_id = PatIdLabeller,
    .default = label_both
)
```

Testing the PatIdLabeller function gives the desired output (though I think, using subset is not most elegant way to do it), e.g.

```
> PatIdLabeller('103')
[1] "Pat 103 (32 y, f)"
```

But using it in ggplot, the IDs are correct, but age and gender are for all the same (last row of patmeta) as you see in the picture.

A subset of my qdat is the following

```
structure(list(pat_id = c(103L, 103L, 103L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 66L, 
66L, 66L, 219L, 219L, 219L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 
232L, 232L, 232L), pat_id_fac = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L
), .Label = c("62", "64", "66", "103", "111", "219", "232"), 
class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
Activity = structure(c(9L, 3L, 9L, 2L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 9L), .Label = c("", 
"Anderes", "Essen", "Hausarbeit", "Hobbies", "Körperpflege", 
"Liegen", "Medienkonsum", "Sozialer Kontakt"), class = "factor")), 
.Names = c("pat_id", "pat_id_fac", "Activity"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L,  
128L, 129L, 130L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 343L, 344L, 345L,   
397L, 398L, 399L, 451L, 452L, 453L), class = "data.frame")


g.bar.activities <-
    ggplot(data=qdat, aes(x=Activity)) +
    geom_bar() +
    facet_wrap(~ pat_id_fac, labeller= globalLabeller)
```

From other questions and answers, I know I could define a character vector, but I am lazy and would like to do it more elegant reusing my patmeta, because the list of study participants will become quite long and evolve over time.

With smaller test data set

```
t <- data.frame("pat_id"=c(103, 103, 103, 219, 219, 219), 
"Activity" = c("sleep", "sleep", "eat", "eat", "eat", "sleep"))
patmeta <- data.frame("pat_id"=c(103, 219), 
"gender"=c("m","f"), "age"=c(32,52))

ggplot(data=t, aes(x=Activity)) + geom_bar() + 
facet_wrap(~pat_id, labeller=globalLabeller)
```

I get exactly what I want. I don't see the difference.

Comment: Can't reproduce without `qdat`.

Comment: Please read: [How to make a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: I added the dput-output of a subset of my original qdat data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the subsetting is not working properly, likely because the `==` is trying to act as a vector along the length of all of the `id`'s being passed in. That is, it is checking each `pat_id` in `patmeta` to see if it matches the `pat_id` passed in. The differences in sorting are somehow leaving only that one `pat_id` matching.

You can see this in action if you try any of the following:

```
PatIdLabeller(c(103, 66))
```

gives `character(0)` and this warning:

> In pat_id == id :   longer object
>   length is not a multiple of shorter object length

because none of the rows return, and R is forced to repeat the elements in the `==`

```
ggplot(data=head(qdat), aes(x=Activity)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~ pat_id, labeller= globalLabeller)
```

gives a plot with duplicated age/gender again, and this warning

> In pat_id == id : longer object length is not a
>   multiple of shorter object length

(ditto above).

Of note, even with your smaller data set, if you reverse the row order of your new `patmeta` (so that 219 is before 103), then run the code you get

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Unknown input

because the labeller is returning an empty `character()` (as above).

I don't have a lot of experience with labellers (this answer was a good chance to explore them), but this one should work by using `left_join` from `dplyr`, rather than trying to use `==`.

```
myLabeller <- function(x){
  lapply(x,function(y){
    toLabel <-
      data.frame(pat_id = y) %>%
      left_join(patmeta)

    paste0("Pat ", toLabel$pat_id
           , " (", toLabel$age, "y, "
           , toLabel$gender, ")")
  })
}
```

and use gives:

```
ggplot(data=qdat, aes(x=Activity)) + geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~pat_id, labeller=myLabeller) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

An alternative option would be to skip the labeller step, and just generate the label you actually want to use directly. Here, just merge the meta data with the patient data (using `left_join` from `dplyr`), then generate a column using the format/style that you want (here, using `mutate` from `dplyr` and `paste0`).

```
forPlotting <-
  qdat %>%
  left_join(patmeta) %>%
  mutate(forFacet = paste0("Pat ", pat_id
                           , " (", age, "y, "
                           , gender, ")"))
```

Then, use that data for plotting, and the new column for faceting.

```
ggplot(forPlotting, aes(x=Activity)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~forFacet) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

gives

[image]

note that the facets are now sorted alphabetically, but you could adjust that as needed by setting the column as a factor with explicitly sorted levels when you make it.

Comment: Yes, this works. And it is not a problem to keep the additional column for me. Though, it seems a bit like a workaround and the straightforward version would be to use a labeller function. I am still curious why it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: I took another look and updated my answer to address the labeller issue directly. I would still generally lean towards  creating a column to use as a label, but that may just be due to my lack of experience with labellers.